# Set PersonContactID

Tags: apex, person-accounts

Is it possible to get the PersonContactID from an Opportunity field lookup.

I am trying to get the PersonContactID to get a different record that is not related to the Opportunity Record itself

I am new to coding and so far nothing i have done has worked

```
public class ID_Document{
    public Identification_Documents__c DocID {get; set;}
    private string AccountId;
    private string opportunityid;
    public ID_Document()
    {
        opportunityid = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('oppId');
        AccountId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Test_ID__c');
        DocID = new Identification_Documents__c();
    }

    public PageReference Save()
    {
        DocID.Account__c = 'AccountId';
        insert DocID;      
        return new PageReference ('/' + opportunityid);
    }
}
```

Comment: Never, ever, hard code an Id.

Comment: arr, sorry that was for testing to much sure i had the correct ID value,

Answer (score 0):

You can query the `PersonContactId` directly by using either the `AccountId` you have (I'm assuming it's the PersonAccount Id) or the `Opportunity.AccountId` if the AcountId is for the PersonAccount.

Either of those will allow you to create a method to directly obtain the PersonContactId. Its important to remember there should only be ONE `ContactID` for a `PersonAccount`, that will allow you to query that Contact using just the `AccountId` in a query that would look something like this:

```
Id contactId = [SELECT Id FROM CONTACT WHERE AccountId = :accountId LImit 1].Id;
```

**EDIT**

**In response to comments...**

The Opportunity will be a child of the Account. Opportunity has a field on it for `AccountId`. If you do not have it at the time you need the `ContactId`, you should be able to query Opportunity to get the Account Id. It will be much easier for you to do that separately than to try to do it in a single query.

Here is how to obtain it using the `opportunityId` variable in your controller:

```
Opportunity opp = [SELECT AccountId FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = : opportunityid limit1];  
// Id of personAccount = opp.AccountId;
Id contactId = [SELECT Id FROM CONTACT WHERE AccountId = :opp.AccountId LImit 1].Id;
```

If you have any issues with the above, either declare `Id personAccount = opp.AccountId` or try using `opp[0].AccountId` and if necessary, use `list<opportunity>opp` in the query declaration. Sometimes these things do not compile as they should when limit 1 is used in the query.

Comment: Hey there... that SoQL is a little wonky. :-)

Comment: Arggh, thanks, was in a rush! Will correct.

Comment: arr i still cant get this code right. Because the Account lookup is on the Opportunity form, do i need to pass through the opportunity id to the query? if so how do i do this?

Comment: If the accountId is not available at the time you need it, you will need to query for it. See my edited answer.